# How to create PAT token in github for an Organization Account

Tags: github, git-clone, personal-access-token

I have been added to my organization, now I am part of the organization in github and have access to a private repo. I am not able to clone the repo in my eclipse as I understood that we need a PAT token to access a private repo, but how do I create PAT for the organization. However I know how to create PAT for my own account, but only if I have PAT token for my organization I can clone the repo in my local.

Answer (score 1):

PAT token allows you also access to all the organization you have access to. But it seem some clients only show personal project. In Xcode I was able to work around this by pasting the repo URL into the search field.